# Enable travis CI to check for package dependencies

Tags: r, dependencies, continuous-integration, travis-ci

## Actual question

What do I need to do in order to enable travis CI to check my package dependencies?

## What I tried

I tried adding the `cran` argument to `.travis.yml` file as describe in [guide](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/) on travis-ci.com.

My `.travis.yml` file looks like this:

```
language: r
warnings_are_errors: yes
sudo: required
cran: http://cran.rstudio.com
r_packages:
- covr
after_success:
- Rscript -e 'covr::codecov()'
```

Yet, I still get the following [error](https://travis-ci.org/rappster/devops/builds/88750569):

```
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped
```

## Session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devops_0.1.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   tools_3.2.2    yaml_2.1.13    memoise_0.2.1  stringi_1.0-1 
[6] stringr_1.0.0  digest_0.6.8   devtools_1.9.1
```

---

## Update

I found out that the error was actually cause by listing some package dependencies in `Suggests:` instead of `Imports:` section of my `DESCRIPTION` file ([build that passed](https://travis-ci.org/rappster/devops/builds/88768106)).

However, I'm still getting a note that the dependency check was skipped as no repository has been set:

```
* checking package dependencies ... NOTE
  No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped
```

Does that mean that a dependency check has not been carried out and, if so, what do I need to change in order to make this happen?

Comment: Did you try with http**s** as the http redirect to https ?

Comment: @Tensibai: changing to `cran = https://cran.rstudio.com` in `.travis.yml` gave me the following [error](https://travis-ci.org/rappster/devops)